# How to Integreate flurry+Admob in single banner?

Tags: iphone, ios6, admob, flurry

We want to integrate Admob banner within flurry ad banner for Ad meditation. We have configured all the code in project and followed this URL http://support.flurry.com/index.php?title=Publisher/Code/Mediation.

But We are not getting banners. 
Please provide me any sample code for flurry+Admob in single banner for iOS SDK.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To implement an Ad Network you must perform the following steps:

1. Include the Ad Network iOS SDK with your app and add it to the project. Follow the instructions from the Ad network on how to complete this step.
2. Implement the appropriate delegate methods in FlurryAdDelegate

An example of implementing AdMob SDK into AppSpot is given in the FlurryAppSpot-iOS-README file inside your SDK folder. Please note that after client-side configuration, you need to create a network mediation campaign on the Flurry website. More details on server-side setup is given here: http://support.flurry.com/index.php?title=Publisher/GettingStarted#campaigns

(Full disclosure: I work at Flurry)